# I can't add a ArcGIS Feature Server Layer

Tags: arcgis-server, layers, qgis-3

4
I want to get the layer from

> http://3d-cpd.bangkok.go.th/ArcGIS/rest/services/BMA3D_2D_WMS_TTD/MapServer

and when I try to add a layer (via add new ArcGis Feature Server Layer)
I got the message

> Layer is not valid: The layer crs='EPSG:32647' filter=''
>   url='http://3d-cpd.bangkok.go.th/ArcGIS/rest/services/BMA3D_2D_WMS_TTD/MapServer/15' table="" sql= is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map.
>   Reason: AFSProvider getObjectIds failed: Error 400 - Unable to
>   complete operation.

What is the cause of this? and could I get the data after all?

Comment: Can you provide more information in the question on how you've tried to add this layer

Comment: If you click on the link and then right click on the link location bar (e.g, Mapserver) and copy the link location, then use that as the url when adding an ArcGISMapServer layer, that might work.  I just was able to do it in my 3.10

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged QGIS, so I assume you're trying to view it there. However, it doesn't even load in a simple JS viewer: http://3d-cpd.bangkok.go.th/ArcGIS/rest/services/BMA3D_2D_WMS_TTD/MapServer?f=jsapi
Console error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response
>   was received.

I dont think there is much you can do. It looks like a Server/Service problem that they have to fix.

In short, your only course of action would to get in touch with the server owners and inform them of the error and hopefully they'll fix it.

Comment: Try searching for it on arcgis.com. Perhaps there's another link to the same layer, or a similar one available.

Comment: Hi KHibma, for me the map in your link is loaded as usual. So is it a problem from the server ? (Thanks for your help btw )

Answer (score 1):

I also get the same error as you when trying to use the ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer functionality.

QGIS generates a request like:

[ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer request](http://3d-cpd.bangkok.go.th/ArcGIS/rest/services/BMA3D_2D_WMS_TTD/MapServer/7/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnIdsOnly=true)

I find I can get some data showing if I use the [WMS interface](http://3d-cpd.bangkok.go.th/ArcGIS/services/BMA3D_2D_WMS_TTD/MapServer/WMSServer?).

One thing to note is the data is scale layered, so for example you'll need to zoom in some way to see anything from the Hydro layer

```
<MaxScaleDenominator>46302.083333</MaxScaleDenominator>
<MinScaleDenominator>188.988095</MinScaleDenominator>
```

Example GetMap request generated by QGIS that shows a map:

> http://3d-cpd.bangkok.go.th/arcgis/services/BMA3D_2D_WMS_TTD/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=660185.5101244432153,1518871.539906768827,667379.4102466796758,1525116.030463516945&CRS=EPSG:32647&WIDTH=932&HEIGHT=809&LAYERS=5&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96

[image: GetMap request for Hydro layer]